# Asynchronous scrolling (APZ) in Edge janky & problematic; not in IE or other browsers

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, scroll, microsoft-edge, onscrolllistener

The Edge browser causes janking of certain divs when they are adjusted by a scroll listener. This janking does not occur in IE, Chrome, Opera, or Firefox.

Even though Firefox doesn't cause janking, it raises a flag in the console when it detects the scroll listener is first employed, and it directs me to this page for explication:

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Mozilla/Performance/ScrollLinkedEffects

The article describes what seems to be an exact desciption of the issue I'm having with Edge:

> In the asynchronous scrolling model, the visual scroll position is
>   updated in the compositor thread and is visible to the user before the
>   scroll event is updated in the DOM and fired on the main thread. This
>   means that the effects implemented will lag a little bit behind what
>   the user sees the scroll position to be. This can cause the effect to
>   be laggy, janky, or jittery — in short, something we want to avoid.

It only offers two solutions, the first of which (position: sticky) only has limited browser support, and the second of which (scroll snapping) has been removed from web standards.

Reaching further, I discovered a good article on APZ (Asynchronous Panning & Zooming) in Edge by its development team:

https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/03/08/scrolling-on-the-web/#ahrEuFu6fybJ1uwj.97

It would be ideal if there were a way to turn APZ on and off, but I can't find a way around it. However Firefox has implemented it poses no problem for my routine, but Edge's implementation is extremely problematic, especially since it provides no support for position: sticky.

Is there another way around this issue? It is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can force edge to turn off it's APZ implementation by wrapping the scrollable element inside another, forcing that wrapper element into it's own layer, and then finally adding in another dummy, position fixed element, inside that wrapper.

Your HTML would be like so:

```
// Wrapper element, forced into it's own layer with translateZ.

<div id="wrapper_element" style="transform: translateZ(0);">

    // Dummy position fixed element to force APZ off.
    <div style="top: 0px; width: 1px; height: 1px; position: fixed; z-index: 1;"></div>

    // Your current scrollable element.
    <div id="your_scrollable_element">

         // Your content

    </div>

</div>
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: For Firefox, how could i turn off it's APZ implementation?

Comment: is there any Microsoft official document about disabling APZ? Since this way sounds like hacky. After applying it, I found it only improves the case when using mouse wheel. But if scroll by dragging a scrollbar, Edge still has a big delay for an scroll event listener.

Comment: @Hawk Unfortunately no, this is the only way to do it as far as I am aware.